# How to express this action in English: "The 2 children are competing with each other for the toy"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Look at this picture.

[image]

The two children are competing with each other for the toy.

How to express this action in English?

Could I say **"The 2 children are scrambling for the toy"?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't be *vocabulary fancy* here!

I'd say:

> Two children are fighting for the toy

[Fighting over a toy](https://parentingfromtheheartblog.com/kids-sharing/) is common among kids.

Though *fight* is a bit strong word, looking at the expressions of the kids, I think it won't be exaggerated. And, when the *context* is clear (children), *fight* word is neutralized for its intensity.

[Even babies fight!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KCF4wqegsCc)

Comment: But, the children are not hitting each other though they may push each other away, they are just trying to pull the toy out of the other.

Comment: @Tom Yes, they aren't actually hitting each other. But "fighting over toys" is a very common phrase to use for this act (of pulling). It's very idiomatic and natural. *If you fight for something, you try in a determined way to get it or achieve it.* See [definition](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fight) 2 in Collins.